# How to edit only some fields in django admin from an extend user model?

Tags: django, django-admin

After looking for the best way to extend user, I followed the way described here (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Now I am looking for a way to let the user edit some of their fields from User (eg. first_name, last_name and email) and from the new class extended. It would be nice if this could be done on the same screen, but I am not sure if this is possible (I don't want to let the permissions editable for non superuser).

So, I have first tried this code in admin, but it not works:

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            fieldsets = super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        else:
            fieldsets = (
                (None, {
                    'fields': ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'last_login', 'date_joined',)
                }),)
        return fieldsets

    # If not superuser, do not show some fields
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        ro_fields = super(MyUserAdmin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            ro_fields = list(ro_fields) + ['username', 'last_login', 'date_joined',]
        return ro_fields

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Here is a piece of my model:

```
class Investigator(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_('User'))
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(_('Force password change'), default=True)
    ...
```

I got no error, but the changes are not saved. What I have to do to let the users edit some specific fields?

Comment: i wouldnot follow the dev docs, 1.6 or 1.7 is good enough

Comment: what is your extended model name? are you extend django `User` model?

Comment: Doniyor, doc from 1.7 says the same: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: Hasan, yes. I edited my question and added a piece of my model.

Answer (score 0):

You need set up permission for the user to edit User model
[image]